# How should I iterate this loop through the table columns to get the id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to fetch all the records checked and get the ids of those.
but the code using foreach does not iterates. It fetches me only the first row id. Here is my code below

```
$("#saveToDocReg").click(function () {
    var just = $("#registerGrid").find("tr").find("td");
    $("#registerGrid").find("tr").find("td").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("input:checkbox").is(':checked')) {
            var ids = $(this).find("input:hidden").val();
            alert(ids);
            var allIds = [];

            for (var x = 0, l = ids.length; x < l; x++) {
                allIds.push(ids[x].value);
            }

            var str = allIds.join(', ');
        }
    });
});
```

And once I get the ids how am I supposed to get it controller. I was facing these issues. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `allIds` and related logic are *inside* your loop iterator function, so they're recreated every time the loop iterator function is called (e.g., for each `td`).

If your goal is to get all the IDs (values from the hidden fields), then it can be a lot simpler than that:

```
$("#saveToDocReg").click(function () {
    var allIds = $("#registerGrid tr td:has(input:checkbox:checked)").map(function() {
        return $(this).find("input:hidden").val();
    }).get();
    alert(allIds.join(', '));
});
```

Changes:

1. The primary change is getting `allIds` *outside* the loop
2. `$("#registerGrid").find("tr").find("td")` can be written using descendant selectors instead: `$("#registerGrid tr td")`
3. Instead of looping through all the `td`s, we only need to loop through ones that have a checked checkbox. We can use `:has` with jQuery's pseudo `:checked` selector.
4. jQuery objects have a `map` function that builds a jQuery object from what you return from each call to a callback; you can then get the underlying array from it using `.get()`

**Live Example:**

```js
$("#saveToDocReg").click(function() {
  var allIds = $("#registerGrid tr td:has(input:checkbox:checked)").map(function() {
    return $(this).find("input:hidden").val();
  }).get();
  alert(allIds.join(', '));
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="saveToDocReg" value="Click Me">
<table id="registerGrid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <input type="hidden" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <input type="hidden" value="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <input type="hidden" value="3">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <input type="hidden" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and really useful explanation. :)